# Discuss convergence of integral

Tags: real-analysis

Discuss the convergence of $\int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{x}} \, dx$

Initially, I started with

$$e^x \ge 1+x$$

Taking $\ln$ on both sides:

$$x \ge \ln(1+x)$$

$$\frac{1}{x} \le \frac{1}{\ln(1+x)}$$

$$e^{\frac{1}{x}} \le (1+x)^{-1}$$

$$e^{\frac{1}{x}} \le \frac{1}{1+x}$$

$$\int_0^1 (1+x) \, dx=\ln(1+x)|_0^1$$

$\int_0^1 (1+x) \, dx$ is divergent. Nothing can be said about $\int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{x}} \, dx$.

Or alternatively,

$$e^x \ge 1+x$$

$$e^{\frac{1}{x}} \ge 1+\frac{1}{x}$$

$$\int_0^1 \left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right) \, dx =x+\ln x |^1_0$$

$\int_0^1 (1+\frac{1}{x}) \, dx$ is divergent. By comparison theorem, $\int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{x}} \, dx$ is also divergent.

My problem is I need a reason why my former method does not work here.

Comment: In your first attempt,  it is not true that $e^{1/\ln(1+x)}=(1+x)^{-1}$. There are other errors/typos.

Comment: Since your first method is inconclusive, it draws no conclusions and so it does not contradict the result of the second method.  So there is absolutely no conflict to resolve here (but it's true that you made some errors in it).  Not every approach has to lead to a conclusive answer.

Comment: The function is decreasing on the interval, so you can bound the integral below by a right Riemann sum and show that the sum diverges as the number of rectangles goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments already pointed out some inaccuracies in your methods. Here's an idea that'll probably make things a little easier: change variable

$$u=\frac1x\implies dx=-\frac{du}{u^2}\implies\int_0^1e^{1/x}dx=-\int_\infty^0e^u\frac{du}{u^2}=$$

$$\int_0^1\frac{e^u}{u^2}+\int_1^\infty\frac{e^u}{u^2}du=$$

and since the second integral diverges$\,(\color{red}*)\,$ so does the original one.

$$(\color{red}*)\;\text{This follows from}\;\;\;\int_1^\infty\frac{e^u}{u^2}du\ge\int_1^\infty\frac{1+u}{u^2}du$$

and we know that $\;\int\limits_1^\infty u^pdu\;$ converges iff $\;p<-1\;$